# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start using Selenium Chromedriver and Chrome on Linux Machine

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run some Selenium automation tests in a Linux Build Agent (in Bamboo), the tests work fine when I run them from a docker, however when I install Chrome and the necessary stuff I need on my agent directly and run them, I get the following error.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.140 (2d9f97485c7b07dc18a74666574f19176731995c-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1155}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
2019-08-26 13:16:30:08S +0100 [SEVERE] onError:Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: '10.41.39.14', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: SeleniumDriver
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: 'xxxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: SeleniumDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:646)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:255)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:237)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:xxxx/status] to be available after 20001 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:102)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:187)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:147)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:77)
    ... 19 more

[DEBUG]   | Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: 'xxxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: SeleniumDriver
```

I have no idea what is wrong here, my docker image also has the same OS with the some version of Chromedrivers. Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
2019-08-26 13:16:30:08S +0100 [SEVERE] onError:Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: '10.41.39.14', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: SeleniumDriver
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=75.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=75.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.140/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 75**

- Presumably you are using *chrome= 76.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v76.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.126/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 76**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.5.3* of *2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z* which is more then **2** years older.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *Selenium Client v3.5.1* , *ChromeDriver v75.0* and the *Chrome Browser v76.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v76.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=76.0.3809.68/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 76.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v76.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.68/notes.txt))